# Split 1st column values to search two other columns and return single value

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm attempting to take a `CONCATENATE`d value in a column (A), `SPLIT` that value in two and `VLOOKUP` two columns in another sheet (same file).  The issue I'm running into is if there are *not* two values to `SPLIT` in the `CONCATENATE`d cells, I get an error.  I can flip my formula to search for two values or one (two values `JOIN`ed with `:` or a single value), but not both.

This is the latest iteration of my formula that's only showing half of the desired results.

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(IF(FIND(":",A3:A),SPLIT(A3:A,":"),A3:A),{materialsData!C2:C,materialsData!D2:D,materialsData!E2:H},4,))
```

[image]
Here is an [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11-ZKieptfD_Nr1ZTare_X2vMKWBEAd_MVF5rAu9ORqg/edit?usp=sharing) of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, {IF(materialsData!D2:D<>"", 
 materialsData!C2:C&":"&materialsData!D2:D, materialsData!C2:C), materialsData!F2:F}, 2, 0)))
```